# why wrong to store a dictionary/map in neo4j as a property

Tags: neo4j

I have a data structure in the form of a tree. So it has vertices within vertices. Neo4j would be a perfect match but alas someone has made a decision that a property can not be a dictionary/map.

I find this strange. Neo4j is all about vertices. So why not accept tree shaped data?
It would seem so intuitive.

I guess it must be for a good reason. Can it be difficult to manage updates? Or handling memory?

Does anyone know?
And does anyone know an alternative to Neo4j that can store a tree-structure? Or maybe an addon or something that handles that?

Comment: if you have a tree, then model it as such: every tree node is a graph node, every branch is a relationship. I'm not really sure what "a vertex within a vertex" is, to be honest.

Comment: Thank you for fast response.
I do have relations. One example. I might have a system for creating content on the screen. Maybe a desktop has relations to its windows. But also the windows have data. In this particular case it might be css styles:
{ background: "blue", width: "200px", ... }.
I am not interested in having such local data represented as relations of their own. 
I view my system as separate trees with relations AND possible tree structured data within any tree. 
Like reality. Everything has relations to OTHER stuff, but ALSO its own tree structured data.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of a map in your properties implies that the data structure is not fully converted to a graph. The node `(:N {p: map})` implies the structure: `(:N)-->(:P {map})`. With the former structure you'd need to query items in the map using something like `match (n:N) where n.p.k = v` which I imagine would be a nightmare for indexing, etc. With the latter you can simply `match (:N)-->(p:P) where p.k = v`.

Comment: Thank you for fast response.
I do have relations. One example. I might have a system for creating content on the screen. Maybe a desktop has relations to its windows. But also the windows have data. In this particular case it might be css styles:
{ background: "blue", width: "200px", ... }.
I am not interested in having such local data represented as relations of their own. 
I view my system as separate trees with relations AND possible tree structured data within any tree. 
Like reality. Everything has relations to OTHER stuff, but ALSO its own tree structured data.